# Synchronization Bulk Insertion Exception

Tags: sql, synchronization, bulkinsert, microsoft-sync-framework

Any one please help me out. I am syncing sql server to client using MS Sync Framework. I am getting this exception at syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand' for table ‘xyz'; the transaction was rolled back. Ensure that the command syntax is correct.

Inner Exception is:
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#B1CF471__ECD9228532A93525'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@changeTable'. The duplicate key value is (0). The data for table-valued parameter \"@changeTable\" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. The statement has been terminated.

There is a store procedure that using above object 'dbo.@changeTable', but I don't know what to do with that??

Comment: have you previously provisioned/deprovisioned scopes on your database?

Comment: It has been provisioned successfully. Exception comes at when I synchronize it.

Comment: The problem is resolved. I just deprovisioned the scope and then again provision it.